# Add a Label or a Title to a Colorbar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, label, title, colorbar

I've tried using the **xlabel**, **ylabel** and **title** functions to do this but all they do is to increase the widths of my colorbars. The text that I want to appear as the label/title doesn't appear at all. Can you please tell me how I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: show your code or some example, this way it is hard to say something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `annotation` such as

```
annotation('textbox',[x y w h])
```

that will display a text over axes, meaning that it will not change the aspect ratio of the colorbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still trying it out but so far it looks very promising! Can you please tell me why the aspect ratio of the colorbar might keep getting changed?

I'm simply writing commands such as ylabel(colorbar,'label') or set(get(colorbar,'ylabel'),'String', 'My Title'). But they change the appearance of the colorbar like I described earlier.

Comment: Don't know why the aspect ratio changes (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't). You can also get the colorbar initial position `pos = get(colorbar, 'Position')`, add a title and then set the position back with `pos = set(colorbar, 'Position', pos)`. I found annotations much easier to hanle.

Comment: You're right. Annotations are really easy to work with. Thanks for your help :)